# Error en formulario de login en PDO

Tags: php, pdo, autenticación

Tengo este PHP para validar mi usuario y contraseña.

El archivo me responde con "Conexion Ralizada" y se queda ahí.

¿Podéis decirme qué hago mal?. Uso contraseñas cifradas.

```
   <?php

 try{
     $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=....com;dbname=...','...','...');
     echo 'Conexion realizada';
    }    

catch (PDOException $ex) {
       echo $ex->getMessage();
       exit;

    }

/* @var $_POST type */
$usuario= $_POST["usuario"];
$pass= $_POST["pass"];


 $query=("SELECT UsuarioLog,PassLog FROM `Login` "
         . "WHERE `UsuarioLog`='".mysql_real_escape_string($usuario)."' and "
         . "`PassLog`='".mysql_real_escape_string($pass)."'"); 

$rs= mysql_query($query); 
$row=mysql_fetch_object($rs); 
$nr = mysql_num_rows($rs);


if($nr == 1){ 

echo 'Error al ingresar sus datos - Error when entering your data'; 

} 

else if($nr == 0) {    

     header("Location:gracias.html");

}   

?>
```

Comment: te redirecciona o te imprime el echo ?

Comment: ¿Podría recomendarte de entrada que dejaras de usar las funciones `mysql_*`? Fueron consideradas obsoletas en PHP 5.5.0 (junio de 2013, hace más de 5 años) y eliminadas completamente en PHP 7.0.0 (en noviembre de 2015, hace casi tres años). Por otro lado, ¿que te aparece en el log de error del servidor web? ¿Algún error o advertencia? Imagino que tendrás algún que otro ya que estás usando `mysql_query` sin establecer conexión (lo haces, sí, pero en PDO, no en `mysql_connect`).

Comment: A parte de la mezcla de funciones, en tu pregunta haces referencia al uso de contraseñas cifradas. ¿Dónde y cómo se cifran las contraseñas? En tu código no veo referencia a ninguna función criptográfica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás mezclando funciones [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/mysql) que han sido marcadas como obsoletas en PHP 5.5.0 (junio de 2013, hace más de 5 años) y eliminadas completamente en PHP 7.0.0 (en noviembre de 2015, hace casi tres años) con llamadas a [`PDO/mysql`](http://php.net/pdo-mysql).

Ya que estás intentando usar PDO, en este ejemplo te detallo paso a paso cómo comprobar correctamente que el usuario y contraseña son los correctos usando PDO:

```
<?php
/* Si no se han mandado los campos necesarios enviamos al formulario */
if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    die('Rellene el formulario');
}

/* Establecemos la conexión a la base de datos */
try {
    $conexión = new \PDO(
        "mysql:dbname=...;host=...;charset=utf8",
        ...,
        ...
    );
    $conexión->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    die("ERROR DE CONEXIÓN: " . $e->getMessage());
}

/* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
try {
    /* Preparamos la consulta. PDO no soporta variables con caracteres no ASCII */
    $consulta = $conexión->prepare('
        SELECT
          UsuarioLog,
          PassLog
        FROM Login
        WHERE
          UsuarioLog = :usuario AND PassLog = :pass
    ');
    /* Asociamos los valores a los entregados en el formulario */
    $consulta->bindValue(':usuario', $_POST['usuario'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $consulta->bindValue(':pass', $_POST['pass'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    /* Ejecutamos la consulta */
    $consulta->execute();
    /* Obtenemos el primer registro (si existe) */
    $datos = $consulta->fetch();
    /* Si no se reciben resultados es porque no existe el usuario con la contraseña proporcionada */
    if ($datos === false) {
        die('Error al ingresar sus datos - Error when entering your data');
    }
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    die("ERROR DE CONEXIÓN: " . $e->getMessage());
}
/* Redirigimos al usuario a la aplicación si todo fue bien */
header('Location: gracias.html');
```

Código adaptado desde el siguiente gist:

- https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/4f706704640d3f4bb6b4acfcaba59eeb

Veo en tu pregunta que indicas que **usas contraseñas cifradas**, pero ni en la consulta SQL ni en el código PHP veo referencias a funciones criptográficas. En este ejemplo y en tu SQL se usan contraseñas sin cifrar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error esta en que estas mostrando texto antes que el `header` (cabeceras)

> **header()** es usado para enviar encabezados HTTP sin formato. Ver la
>   especificación » [HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) para más información sobre
>   encabezados HTTP.
>
> Recuerde que header() debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por
>   pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde
>   PHP. Es un error muy común leer código con funciones como include o
>   require, u otro tipo de funciones de acceso de ficheros que incluyen
>   espacios o líneas en blanco que se muestran antes de llamar a la
>   función header(). Sucede el mismo problema cuando se utiliza un solo
>   fichero PHP/HTML.

Esto esta en [Header](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) en la documentación de php.net

Entonces, yo te recomiendo que quites el `echo 'Conexion realizada'`. 
Ya que si funciona no necesitas que te lo muestre. Si lo que quieres es hacer debug, prueba de comentar el `header` y poner un `echo 'ahora viene la redireccion'`, o incluso hacer un `print_r($nr)` para saber si la consulta te esta devolviendo algo.

En conclusión, **no muestres nada por pantalla antes de llamar a un header**